# Unable to connect to Database: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

Why while I run the command `mongod` on server everything is ok and when I close ssh session on putty I see such error.

> Unable to connect to Database: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017:
>   Connection refused

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your setup, it's kind of impossible for us to give you a proper answer. It would just be guesswork. Is it a local virtual or a remote server? OS? Is the code on the same server as mongo?

Comment: This Is DigitalOcean Ubuntu14.04 remote server, yes the code is on the same server as mongo

Comment: Have you tried to start mongo with `sudo service mongod start`?

Comment: Yes I have that is a result http://prntscr.com/fgvkv0

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the mongo server is being run in the ssh session you are opening when you connect. You'll have to detach the mongo server from your session by using `disown` or by using a utility such as [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) or screen. This will allow your mongo server process to keep running after you have disconnected your ssh session.

Alternatively, as was mentioned in [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405513/unable-to-connect-to-database-failed-to-connect-to-localhost27017-connection/44410293#comment75813198_44405513), if you run your mongo server as a service, you'll be able to disconnect from the ssh session and still  have your server process running.

Starting mongo as a service would look something like this -

```
sudo service mongod start
```

---

So to explain it simply, when you connect via ssh, you are provided a shell on the server to execute commands. The moment you disconnect from your ssh session, your mongo server exits because it has no shell to run on. The shell that it did have was closed when you exited your ssh session.